# how to get different Instagram feeds?

Tags: wordpress, instagram, instagram-api

I build a instagram widget in my wordpress theme. And now I want to do a website demo, I want to display some ins feeds of famous instagram authors with my access token. But it seems that I can only display my own instagram feeds with my access token and user id. why? is ins change its API? I saw some author at themeforest can still display different instagram feed of famous ins authors. Could you teach me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To the first question. Yes, Instagram [restricted access](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/)

> Every new app created on the Instagram Platform starts in Sandbox
>   mode. Apps in this mode can use any API endpoint but are restricted to
>   a limited number of users and media. This is great for developing and
>   testing your app.
>
> To go Live and fully access Instagram content, you will need to submit
>   your application for review and approval. Once reviewed, you will only
>   be able to request users the Permission Scopes for which your app was
>   approved. Because of this, your application may not be able to use
>   some API endpoints unless the corresponding permissions were reviewed
>   and approved.

But you can get feeds making calls to web-version with `?__a=1` parameter. In this case you recieve json. You need to write some code:

```
$otherPage = 'nasa';
$profileUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/$otherPage/?__a=1";

$iterationUrl = $profileUrl;
$tryNext = true;
$limit = 100;
$found = 0;
while ($tryNext) {
    $tryNext = false;
    $response = file_get_contents($iterationUrl);
    if ($response === false) {
        break;
    }
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    if ($data === null) {
        break;
    }
    $media = $data['user']['media'];
    $found += count($media['nodes']);
    var_dump($media['nodes']);
    if ($media['page_info']['has_next_page'] && $found < $limit) {
        $iterationUrl = $profileUrl . '&max_id=' . $media['page_info']['end_cursor'];
        $tryNext = true;
    }
}
```

If you need only 12 media from one feed, your code can be simplier (without `while`). In both cases use `$media` to save a feed in your storage, then display it on your pages.

Comment: It has been stopped. any other way is there?

Answer (score -1):

Please go through the instagram feed wordpress plugin  **https://wordpress.org/plugins/evm-social-gallery/**, For instagram feed for wordpress website.